# Редактор на javascript

Tags: javascript

Ищу простейший встраиваемый текстовый редактор на javascript со вставкой объектов (изображения, файлы, видео) и api сходным с [imperavi redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) (имею в виду легкодоступные php-обработчики на стороне сервера). TinyMCE и CKeditor не предлагать.

Comment: notepad++?

Comment: imperavi redactor, в таком случае чем не устроил?

Comment: [webstorm][1]



[phpDesigner][2]


  [1]: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/
  [2]: http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=phpdesigner&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mpsoftware.dk%2Fphpdesigner.php&ei=5tXNTrCeMsiSOsqU1Y4P&usg=AFQjCNFp-BM3GV5bYuCUKf7gL4_NE82huw&cad=rja

Comment: Человеку нужен редактор встраиваемый в веб-страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо указанных, вы можете

1. создать свой собственный редактор на основе [closure-library](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/), но это потребует усилий,
2. использовать [YUI 2: Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/),
3. использовать [openWYSIWYG](http://www.openwebware.com/).

Comment: Видимо придеться воспользоваться вариантом 1. Спасибо.